# SwiftUI: How to "swipe delete" an element in nested ForEach (grouped)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to created a **dynamic grouped List** in SwiftUI and I wondering how to implement an `onDelete` in this case. From what I have read about [this method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/foreach/3364106-ondelete) it takes on an action that receives an [IndexSet](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/indexset). That is all fine when you only have a single ForEach (no grouping) but when you add nested ForEach (implemented grouping) implementing "deleting with swipe" of items functionality breaks. The issue is that I am not sure if the `onDelete` should go on the outer `ForEach` or the inner one, both do not work as there is no way to detect from which `Category` object in `items` the passed `IndexSet` is so I can perform the removal of items. Any thoughts? Here is my model and view:

model:

```swift
class Product: Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

class Category: Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    let id = UUID()
    @Published var products = [Product]()
    var categoryName = ""
}

class Categories: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items = [Category]()
}
```

and view:

```swift
struct ProductListView: View {
    @ObservedObject var categories: Categories = Categories()


    var body: some View {
            List {
                ForEach(categories.items) { category in
                    Section(header: Text(category.categoryName)) {
                        ForEach(category.products) { product in
                            Text(product.name)
                        }
                        .onDelete(perform: self.removeItems)
                    }
                }
            }
            .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
    }

    func removeItems(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        // This does not work correctly with nested ForEach

        // How to correctly remove the swiped element from the `.products`
        // Not sure how to find the correct `Category` which element was swiped.

        offsets.forEach{ offset in
            print(offset) // prints 0, 1 etc.
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just pass the category to your removeItems function

```
.onDelete(perform: { offsets in
              self.removeItems(at offsets: offsets, from category: category)
          })



func removeItems(at offsets: IndexSet, from category: Category) {
    // You now know which category to delete from and at which index
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing is simple by using the `remove` function available on the [Mutable Collection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/rangereplaceablecollection/3349502-remove).  So if your function can be changed as below

```swift
func removeItems(at offsets: IndexSet) {
  category.items.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
}
```

Since you have the name `items` both at `Category` and `Categories`, it might confuse the dev.